# Removing periodic noise from an image using the Fourier Transform

Tags: image-processing

So I have an image that has horizental lines (noise), in other to get ride of them I worked with the Fourier Transform, however this is the result I get.
[image]
Here is my code:

```
figure, imshow(im3);
frequencyImage = fftshift(fft2(im3));
% Take log magnitude so we can see it better in the display.
amplitudeImage = log(abs(frequencyImage));
minValue = min(min(amplitudeImage))
maxValue = max(max(amplitudeImage))
imshow(amplitudeImage, []);
amplitudeThreshold = 10.9;
brightSpikes = amplitudeImage > amplitudeThreshold; % Binary image.
imshow(brightSpikes);
% Filter/mask the spectrum.
frequencyImage(brightSpikes) = 0;
% Take log magnitude so we can see it better in the display.
amplitudeImage2 = log(abs(frequencyImage));
minValue = min(min(amplitudeImage2))
maxValue = max(max(amplitudeImage2))
imshow(amplitudeImage2, [minValue maxValue]);
filteredImage = ifft2(fftshift(frequencyImage));
amplitudeImage3 = abs(filteredImage);
minValue = min(min(amplitudeImage3))
maxValue = max(max(amplitudeImage3))
imshow(amplitudeImage3, [minValue maxValue]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You removed not just any "bright spikes", you also removed the DC component. That's the "brightest spike" by far.